# In a Substrate runtime module how do I compare an input hash to a known default hash value?

Tags: parity, substrate

I am trying to compare an unknown `input_hash` with a `default_hash_value` which my runtime is aware of.

The default_hash_value in hex is `5198bfa9da6f9c9d22dd2b0ce301dde9fd3c5826a117705d3ffa415d83a6bde8` generated using Blake2 hashing algorithm from a string `A nice default hash`.

a) I presume `T::Hash` the correct input type, but...

b) How to I encode `default_hash_value` in my runtime module so that I can make the comparison something along the lines of:

```rust
if let default_hash_value = input_hash {
    //... this is the default value do, something
} else {
    //... this is not the default value, do something else
}
```

The main issue is encoding the known value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
fn compare(input: T::Hash) {
    let default_hash = hex!("5198bfa9da6f9c9d22dd2b0ce301dde9fd3c5826a117705d3ffa415d83a6bde8");

    ensure!(default_hash == input.encode().as_slice(), "not equal");
}
```

Here I converted both values to a byte array and then compared them.

The `hex!` macro comes from the `hex-literal` crate: https://docs.rs/hex-literal/0.2.1/hex_literal/

> This crate provides hex! macro for converting hexadecimal string literal to byte array at compile time.

And the `T::Hash` is converted using the `parity_codec::Encode` trait: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/parity_scale_codec/index.html#encode

> encode(&self) -> Vec: Encodes the type data and returns a slice.

Not sure if this is the most efficient or ergonomic way, but I have tested it to work.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this in the testing for the SRML modules, but could not get it to work (didn't know where to find the macro definition). The `hex_literal` crate is not included in `Cargo.toml` for node-template, even though the `hex!` macro is often used in testing. I think it should be added.

Comment: In general, it is good practice to only include crates which you actually use. So unless we use it in the node template, I don't think it will be added by default